# Passing/Comparing by reference for javascript objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to compare two objects. I use socket.io to send the `nodes` object to the client.

My `server.js` goes:

```
var nodes = {'101':{ID:'101',x:100,y:200},
             '102':{ID:'102',x:200,y:200}};
socket.emit('message', nodes);
```

In my client, I'd like to create a copy of the object `nodes` only for the first time it receives. Save it to the variable `oldNodes` and the next time the socket receives the `nodes` object, do a comparison with `oldNodes` and output which property has been changed.

E.g., if it receives `var nodes = {'101':{ID:'101',x:100,y:200},'102':{ID:'102',x:200,y:300}};`, 
it should print(console.log) that `nodes[102].y is changed`.

`client.html` :

```
socket.on('message', function(nodes){
    if (oldNodes == undefined){
        var oldNodes = nodes;
   }
   else{
       //compare oldNodes & nodes
       //print result
  }
});
```

For copying, `var oldNodes = nodes;` is not what I want since javascript passes objects as a reference. So, even if `oldNodes & nodes` have the same content, `(oldNodes == nodes)` will produce a `false`. How do I copy the object and **COMPARE** its properties efficiently?

Comment: You do realize that's not valid Javascript? `'101'{}` should be `'101':{}`

Comment: You can do a deep object copy to avoid the reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Comment: use libraries like lodash/underscore.

Comment: You can use some like this: https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch

Answer (score 2):

From your code it seems like the problem is not passbyref related. If you declare oldNodes outside of your function and then assign it with var inside the if statement, oldNodes will not be defined in the else block. This might be what you are looking for?

```
if (oldNodes == undefined){
    oldNodes = nodes;
}
```

Comment: i can't write `oldNodes = nodes;` It'll just copy the reference to the "nodes" object. So, when I change something to `oldNodes`, the `nodes` object will be effected, too.

Comment: Have you tested this? The nodes that are getting pushed to you in the socketio code is from ws and isn't referring to anything else.

Comment: `if (oldNodes == undefined){
    oldNodes = nodes;
}
oldNodes[101].x = 500;
console.log(nodes[101].x);`

console prints 500 in the first time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
if (typeof oldNodes === 'undefined') {
    // use deep copy of Jquery
    var oldNodes = jQuery.extend(true, {}, nodes); 
} else {
   //compare oldNodes vs. nodes
   //print result
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

1) Simple clone:

```
var oldNodes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nodes));
```

2) Use this lib to compare: https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch

Answer (score 1):

As you said

**For copying, var oldNodes = nodes; is not what I want since javascript passes objects as a reference.**

This is not the case here:

**Your code is right, just go with it, you won't get any reference issue** as every time you receives a data from socket it is a **new Object**.

This is the final code you need, give it a try

```
var oldNodes = undefined
socket.on('message', function(nodes){
    createFirstTime_And_CompareElse(nodes)
});


var createFirstTime_And_CompareElse = function(newObj) {
    if (oldNodes == undefined){
        oldNodes = newObj;
    }
    else{
        //compare oldNodes & newObj
        //print result
        for(each in oldNodes) {
            for(subEach in oldNodes[each])
            if(oldNodes[each][subEach] != newObj[each][subEach]) {
                console.log("newObj[" + each + "]" + "[" + subEach + "] is changed")
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: let's assume that I make some changes to oldNodes.
Will the newObj be changed right after my modification to oldNodes? Cuz there are other parts of the program(other objects that change according to the change in newObj) that depends on that newObj,